# Definition of degeneracy

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

A graph $G$ is said to be $k$-degenerate if every subgraph of $G$ has a vertex of degree at most $k$.

I'm having a difficult time understanding this definition. Wouldn't this just suggest that $k=\Delta (G)$, since there exists a subgraph with a vertex of maximum degree?

---

**EDIT:**
If I am understanding this correctly, $k=\max\{\delta (H_1),\delta (H_2),...,\delta (H_n)\}$ for every subgraph $H_i\subseteq G$, where $1\le i\le n$. But since $G \subseteq G$ and $\delta (H_i) \leq \delta (G)$ for all $i$, wouldn't this imply $k=\delta(G)$? I know this can't be correct (why else create this definition).

Comment: A note on the choice of words: A trivial consequence of the definition is that a $k$-degenerate graph $G$ is always $n$-degenerate for all $n \geq k$. The smallest $k$ for which $G$ is $k$-degenerate is called the _degeneracy_ of the graph, which is what you probably are referring to when giving a single value for "$k$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A graph $G$ is always $\Delta(G)$-degenerate. Nevertheless, it can also be $k$-degenerate for $k<\Delta(G)$. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_%28graph_theory%29) lists some examples, the simplest of them being a tree, which has degeneracy $1$ and therefore is $k$-degenerate for each $k\geq 1$, regardless of $\Delta(G)$.

Comment: That makes sense. The more I think about it (if I am understanding this correctly), $k=\max\{\delta (H_1),\delta (H_2),...,\delta (H_n)\}$ for every subgraph $H_i\subseteq G$, where $1\le i\le n$. But since $G \subseteq G$ and $\delta (H_i) \leq \delta (G)$ for all $i$, wouldn't this imply $k=\delta(G)$? I know this can't be correct (why else create this definition).

Comment: You always have $\delta\leq k$ but it can be strict. Take for example a complete graph with $\ell$ vertices and add one vertex adjacent to only one vertex of the complete graph. Then $\delta(G)=1$ and $k=\ell$.

Comment: Did you mean $k=l-1$? Regardless, that makes complete sense, thanks!

Comment: yes you are right, it's $k=\ell-1$ !

Comment: @Bonnaduck If you mean minimum degree by $\delta (G)$ then $\delta (G)\geq \delta (Hi)$, isn't correct. Don't you think? Take for example graph of Aline, in above comment, $\delta (G)= 1$ but there are subgraphs with higher $\delta (H_i)$. If you meant maximum degree, then you should use $\Delta (G)$ notation I guess.

Comment: How can k be l-1? Given that we have a complete graph, let's say M, of size l, and it's a subset of G, $\delta{(M))} = l$.

Comment: @NeoMHacker The degree of a vertex of complete graph of order $l$ is $l-1$.